# Create a control in Resources and reuse it in XAML WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources

I just try to create a simple Symbol/Geometry/Control and change and reuse it in several places in the same window.

Example: a black square with a circle in the middle.

The circle should then change between red and green (similar to a one-light stoplight). Doing it with images would work. I try to solve it as a Window resource, but I do not unterstand.

The idea: I write it into a resource, here I try into a Canvas:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Canvas x:Key="Ampel">
        <Rectangle Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="52" Stroke="Black"       VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50"/>
        <Ellipse x:Name="RedGreen" Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="11,12,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="28" RenderTransformOrigin="0.214,0.256"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then I would like to place it inside a Grid or a Panel, but how do I reference it?

```
<Canvas x:Name="RedGreen1" Height="50" Width="50" DataContext="{DynamicResource Ampel}" />
```

This does not return a compiler-error, but shows nothing in the window. It also doesn't work with WrapPanel or anything else.

And if it would work, how could I refer to it in code-behing for changing the color of the circle. Something like `RedGreen1.RedGreen.Fill=Brushes.Green`?

I read the articles about stoplights. Is it really necessary to create an UserControl or is there a way to solve it with window.resources?

General idea of the application is to have a list of parameters. Each one with a correct input is marked green and computation can only be started, if all parameters are marked green.

And even if I get it running with red/green-images, I try to understand WPF/XAML better  and learn something.

Thank you.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When you define a arbitrary Control in `Resources`, you can use it in the future in Control which have property `Content` and derived from `Control` class. These are the followings: [`ContentControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [`Label`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.label.aspx), [`ContentPresenter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), etc.

Also you must set [`x:Shared="False"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970778%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for resource if you want to use this resource in many Controls, because `x:Shared="True"` by default then one Resource is common to all - in this case, the system swears on the duplicate Content. When `x:Shared="False"` when is created Resource for each element whenever it its request. Quote from [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970778%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> When set to *false*, modifies WPF resource-retrieval behavior so that requests for the attributed resource create a new instance for each request instead of sharing the same instance for all requests.

Example:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Canvas x:Key="Ampel" x:Shared="False">
        <Rectangle Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="52" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50"/>
        <Ellipse x:Name="RedGreen" Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="11,12,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="28" />
    </Canvas>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ContentControl Name="MyContentControl" Content="{StaticResource Ampel}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />        
    <Label Name="MyLabel" Content="{StaticResource Ampel}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <ContentPresenter Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{StaticResource Ampel}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

To change the `Fill` of Ellipse in code-behind, you can like this:

```cs
private void ChangeBackground_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var canvas = MyContentControl.Content as Canvas;

    if (canvas != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in canvas.Children)
        {
            if (item is Ellipse)
            {
                ((Ellipse)item).Fill = Brushes.Green;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `x:Shared="False"` did the trick. Funny that it won't show in auto-complete

Comment: Wh the hell would you change the fill in the code behind? this is not in sync with MVVM.

Comment: you bind it to a propert bound tou a converter

Answer (score 8):

canvas is not having template property thats why we are using contencontrol here.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="Ampel" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="52" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50"/>
            <Ellipse x:Name="RedGreen" Fill="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="11,12,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="28" RenderTransformOrigin="0.214,0.256"/>
        </Canvas>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources >

<ContentControl  Template="{StaticResource Ampel}" Tag="Red" ></ContentControl>
<ContentControl  Template="{StaticResource Ampel}" Tag="Green" ></ContentControl>
<ContentControl  Template="{StaticResource Ampel}" Tag="Blue" ></ContentControl>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: please see the answer of Anatoliy Nikolaev, for me it seems with the Shared-idea a little bit more compact. Nevertheless, thanks a lot.

Answer (score -2):

You can use C# code by heritage:

```
public class customBottum : Buttom
{
        int var1;
        bool var2;

        public customBottum()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        other function ...
}
```