# WPF, XAML. Using the same context menu (saved as resourse) in different ListViews (with binding commands)

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, command, contextmenu

I want to save a context menu as a resource like this

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="MyMenu">
    <MenuItem Header="Add"
              Icon="..." />
    <MenuItem Header="Delete"
              Icon="..." />
    ...
</ContextMenu>
```

and then use it in different places like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="Users" ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyMenu}"
<ContextMenu.MenuItems(Add).Command = AddUserCommand/>
<ContextMenu.MenuItems(Delete).Command = DeleteUserCommand/>
...
<ListView x:Name="DataBases" ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyMenu}"
<ContextMenu.MenuItems(Add).Command = AddDbCommand/>
<ContextMenu.MenuItems(Delete).Command = DeleteDbCommand/>
```

Note. I hope I know how to implement it in MVVM, but for the moment I would like to get a noMVVM, noBehindCode solution. Is it possible ?

**Update1**
The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22960220/create-a-control-in-resources-and-reuse-it-in-xaml-wpf) is not for me.
It doesn't explain **how to bind different commands to ContextMenu Items** (when ContextMenu ia a recourse). Note that items in menus Users and DataBases have the same Commands: Add, but Commands to bind are different AddUserCommand and AddDbCommand.
That's all I need.

Answer (score 0):

add x:Shared="False" to resource:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="MyMenu" x:Shared="False">
```